# How do I open a FITS file from a URL in astropy?

Tags: python, urllib2, astropy

I have a .fits file at a URL that I would like to read into Python as if was just on my machine. What I've tried is:

```
import urllib2 as url, astropy.io.fits as fits
target_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bdnyc/spex_prism_U50171_0835%2B19_chiu06.fits'
obj = url.urlopen(target_url)
dat = fits.open(obj)
```

But I just get `IOError: File-like object does not have a 'write' method, required for mode 'ostream'.`

Even if I set `mode='readonly'` in `fits.open()` it says it can't write to the file-like object.

Is there a way to open .fits files from a URL? Or to convert the .fits file bytes returned by `urlopen()` back into an HDUList?

Comment: The Laughing Man has the correct answer below--you can just pass a URL directly in to `fits.open()`.  Passing in a urlopen object has never been supported, though I think it should be.  The error message you get is misleading, if nothing else.  I've opened an issue for this: https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/4165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation of `astropy.io.fits.open`](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/io/fits/api/files.html), it has an option to read the contents of a .fits file from a URL:

> cache : bool, optional
>
> If the file name is a URL, download_file is
>   used to open the file. This specifies whether or not to save the file
>   locally in Astropy’s download cache (default: True).

Which means you didn't have to use `urllib2`. You can just feed `target_url` to `fits.open` right away, as it calls `astropy.utils.data.download_file` on the URL before opening it. See my code below.

```
In [1]: import astropy.io.fits as fits

In [2]: target_url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bdnyc/spex_prism_U50171_0835%2B19_chiu06.fits'

In [3]: dat = fits.open(target_url)

In [4]: dat
Out[4]: [<astropy.io.fits.hdu.image.PrimaryHDU at 0x219a9e8>]
```

Comment: `fits.open` will open the URL whether or not caching is enabled.  If `cache==True`, a copy of the downloaded data will be saved on disk, then future attempts to download the same file will use the cached version

Comment: I did not say that caching is needed to open the URL. Rather, in the documentation, it says that a URL can be fed to `fits.open`. I was merely making a point that the method can indeed open a URL, something OP wasn't aware of.